# Por que as diretivas nativas do angular começam com NG?

Tags: angularjs

Sempre me perguntei isso, mas finalmente tive a coragem de perguntar: Qual é o significado do `NG` nas bibliotecas do angular?

Aparentemente não tem nada a ver a palavra *Angular* com o prefixo *NG*.

Existe alguma explicação plausível para isso?

Comment: Aparentemente tem muito a ver. A**ng**ular.

Comment: Imaginava que alguém iria negativar :p. Paz e amor!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Conforme esta resposta [What does the ng stand for in Angular.js directives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14669368/1518921) e a primeira pergunta do *FAQ* no angular: https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq

> **Why is this project called "AngularJS"? Why is the namespace called "ng"?**
>
> Because HTML has Angular brackets and "ng" sounds like "Angular".

Porque "ng" soa como "Angular", quero dizer o som que `ng` faz é semelhante a falar `angu`.

No inglês a palavra angular seria pronunciada como [`[ang-gyuh-ler]`](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/angular) (lembrando que `a` lembra no português o som de `E` um pouco "apagado" em algumas palavras), sendo assim a semelhança esta em `ang-gy` provavelmente.

> **Nota:** "semelhante" ou "soar como" não são as mesmas coisas que ser igual ou idêntico

Comment: Muito bom! Agora temos um material em português sobre o assunto. Obrigado pela contribuição :)